# Finding all the ancestors of the current XML node

Tags: xml, dom, xpath

I want to get all ancestors of current xml node. For example:

```
<nav url="navurl">
  <l lo="def">XML Parsing</l> 
  <m url="M Level 1">
    <l lo="en_GB">Location</l> 
    <m url="M Level 2">
      <l lo="en_GB">Other Countries</l> 
      <m url="M Level 3">
        <l lo="en_GB">Europe</l> 
        <u url="U Level 4">
          <l lo="en_GB">Austria</l> 
        </u>
        <m url="M Level 4">
          <l lo="en_GB">Slovakia</l> 
          <u url="U Level 5">
            <l lo="def">Applications</l> 
          </u>
        </m>
        <u url="U Level 4">
          <l lo="en_GB">NewUrl</l> 
        </u>
      </m>
    </m>
  </m>
</nav>
```

Here is the expected output:

```
O/p:
1: m:->m:->m:->u:->l ( Till Australia)
2: m:->m:->m:->m:->l (Till Slowakia)
3: m:->m:->m:->m:->u (Till  Applications)
4: m:->m:->m:->u (Till New URL)
```

Please note that 'm','l' and 'u' are the only tag names and these can be used by 'N' number of times in repetitive fashion.  How can I get this output?

Comment: have you tried `ancestor-or-self` or even just `ancestor` axes?

Comment: Hi JWilley, Thanks for reply. May I know what are they and how can I use in Java Console application?

Comment: Sure, check out [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp)

Comment: -1 for mistaking Australia with Austria :P *jk*

Comment: I would really hesitate to send a user to w3schools to learn about XPath. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120621/w3fools-alternatives) Instead, how about: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html

Comment: BTW you will be more likely to get detailed help if you show some code that you have written and tell specifically where you are having trouble.